# script to make entrys in googlecalendar ,but its not working

Tags: javascript, calendar

i have trid to make a webbapp which its can make an entry in my googlecalendar with googlescript but its not working ,its take the date from the start and the enddate from the textboxes and send it to googlecalendar, can someone tell me where is my error?

```
function doGet() {
     var app=UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test app');
     var pan1=app.createHorizontalPanel();

     app.add(pan1);
     var txt1=app.createTextBox().setId('txt1').setName('txt1');
      var btn1=app.createButton().setText('Start').setId('btn1');
      btn1.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("start"));
      var pan2=app.createHorizontalPanel();
      app.add(pan2);
      var txt2=app.createTextBox().setId('txt2').setName('txt2');
      var btn2=app.createButton().setText('End').setId('btn2');
     btn2.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("ende"));
    pan1.add(txt1);
    pan1.add(btn1);
    pan2.add(txt2);
    pan2.add(btn2);
    var pan3=app.createHorizontalPanel();
    var btn3=app.createButton().setText('Eintragen').setId('btn3');
     btn3.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("stunde_eintragen"));
    pan3.add(btn3);
    app.add(pan3);


     return app;
    }

    function start() {
    var app =UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    app.getElementById("txt1").setText(new Date());
    return app;

    }
    function ende() {
    var app =UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    app.getElementById("txt2").setText(new Date());
    return app;

    }

    function stunde_eintragen (e){
    var app=UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var cal=CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
    var txt11= e.parameter.txt1;
    var txt22= e.parameter.txt2;
    cal.createEvent("Arbeit", new Date('txt11.toString()'), new Date('txt22.toString()'), {location:'Nap room'});

    return app;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Date('txt11.toString()')
```

Putting script you want to execute in quotes won't work. txt11 doesn't exist its txt1 and it should not be in quotes.

```
new Date(txt1.toString())
```

Also, you need to use the addCallbackElement(widget) on the ServerHandler (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_serverhandler#addCallbackElement)

You should practice with a working example from Google and read up on what the functions do from the documentation.